# gwt uibinder: do not call parent.add(child) automatically

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Instead I want to declare parent and child as @UiField and call parent.add(child, someLayout)

Comment: Which UI element has method add(child, somelayout)?

Answer (score 0):

You could override add(child) method on the parent so it calls properly to add(child, somelayout).

```
   @Override
  public void add(Widget w) {
    add(w, somelayout)
  }
```

Anyway, as Peter says, we would need more information.